# Kendo grid schema.model.fields field validation on keypress?

Tags: kendo-grid

Instead of creating functions and calling those, can I trigger the Kendo Grid schema > model > fields > my_field > validation when a key is pressed in the input fields?

```
schema: {

    model: {
        fields: {                                   
            field: { type: "string",
            validation: {                                                            
                ifieldValidation: function (input) { 
                //  My code here. Instead of putting all this in separate function can I trigger this validation somehow?
                return true;
                }
            return true;
            }
        },   
    },
```

... more fields

```
$("#myselector").on("keydown", ".input-field", function (e) {
  // instead of creating functions and calling those, can I trigger the Kendo Grid schema > model > fields > my_field > validation for example call the ifieldValidation ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, so I'm answering my question in case someone needs this too:

```
$("#mygrid").on("keydown", ".my-input", function (e) {
mygrid.options.schema.model.fields.myfieldname.validation.mycustomvalidationfunction($(this));
});
```